# Python docker-compose interpreter in Pycharm: Couldn't find docker binary

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I am trying to configure the remote python docker-compose interpreter in PyCharm Professional. I am able to run a small project (https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/#comment-370730) from the docker container. But when I try to configure it for debugging, setting up of remote interpreter gives me an error saying that docker binary couldn't be found and tells me to install docker.

[docker binary error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOAyp.png)

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I hit this same issue, from a Mac. I was able to work around it by opening Pycharm from the terminal. 
You can do so by running: `/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm`

Then try configuring the docker-compose interpreter again.

This seems to be an open bug in Pycharm. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31727

Comment: The issue seems to be that `docker` is not included in the `PATH` variable from the way Pycharm is started through Mac, but starting it up from the terminal works because it includes it in the PATH.

Comment: The same worked for PHPStorm, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just had to restart my IDE.  Might be worth trying that before going to any other lengths.

My theory is maybe that Docker was not started up when I opened the IDE, as I had just turned on my computer. PhpStorm is what I was using.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had started Docker after Pycharm. Starting Pycharm after Docker was up and running fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For those who still getting such error, I have a workaround with setting PATH with docker binary directory in "Environment variables"
[image]